# Как создать выпадающее меню битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Мне нужно добавить пункт меню,чтобы при его наведении появлялось всплывающее меню с пунктами которые ведут по определённым ссылкам в новой вкладке,пункт меню я уже добавил,а как дальше

Comment: `Мне нужно написать приложение. IDE я уже открыл. Что дальше? `

Comment: Как вы представляете ответ на ваш вопрос?